# NPM cannot find module bash

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, terminal, command-line-interface

I have installed and uninstalled node and cant see to get the thing to work right.

When I type `node -v` I get the version back but if i type `npm -v` I get this error

```
module.js:544
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
```

While possibly unrelated, I recently started using gulp.js and that's when the issue began to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you have some permission errors with the npm `node_modules` package.

Simply delete your `node_modules` folder, then reinstall node.

**Clearing global node modules**

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

**Reinstalling Node and npm**

```
brew install node
```

or download and install using the node installer: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

> To see if Node is installed, type `node -v in` Terminal. This should print the version number.
>
> To see if NPM is installed, type `npm -v` in Terminal. This should print the version number.

Comment: :( Trent now node -v does not work and npm -v . It got worse.

Comment: Sorry to hear. I’m mobile right now, but can you try running the first command now to uninstall node modules, then install using the installable package on nodejs.org website?

Comment: Note, you may need to restart terminal for packages to be accessible by command line.

Comment: for the save! using nodejs.org did it for me by adding the bash command to my local/bin folder since it was missing.

Comment: @Justin, I've edited my answer to include this solution. Thanks for the 'accepted answer'!